# Asking informal questions with 何

Tags: grammar, word-choice, colloquial-language, questions, spoken-language

how do you form informal questions with 何 and without ですか？
would 何 just go at the end?

「あなたの大好きな季節何？」

and is it appropriate to leave off です or だ with な adjectives and nouns? i’ve seen 〜なの？used, but i’m not quite sure what the rules are on that.

「これは食べものなの？」
vs
「これはたべもの？」

basically i’d like some guidelines on informal questions in japanese! i keep struggling on what sounds normal because i don’t want to be overly formal and use ですか？all the time!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways you could go with this. Informal language tends to be a bit different between males and females, for one. In your first example,「好きな季節は？」or「どの季節が一番好き（だ、なんだ、なの）？」would work. Here, だ is more masculine-ish, なんだ is also somewhat masculine-ish and softer, なの is feminine-ish. You also probably wouldn't want to use 大好き here, since you presumably don't know if the other person has a season they like that much. It is possible to say e.g.「僕の大好きな季節はな～んだ？さあ、当ててみて」though.

「これ、食べもんなの？」,「これは食べ物なのか？」,「これは食べ物か？」are all pretty normal ways to ask the question.「これって、食べられるの？」「これ、食べられるか？」are similar ways to ask the same question (well, they literally mean "is this edible?" though).「これはたべもの？」can certainly work (it can sound cute/funny), but if you don't want to sound like a foreigner you probably don't want to use it.

For some formal → informal examples:

> 「どこへ行きましょうか？」　→　「どこへ行こうか？」　⇔　「どこ行こうか？」
>
> 「何をしているんですか？」　→　「何をしてる（の）？」　⇔　「何してんの？」
>
> 「それ、やめてくれませんか？」　→　「それ、やめてくれる？」
>
> 「どうですか？」　→　「どう？」
>
> 「これでいいですか？」　→　「これでいい？」

Comment: thank you so much for this long and detailed answer! it means a lot. i have a few follow-up questions though. why is the format for confirming nouns な and の？what is the purpose of adding な？and is の in 「これ、食べもんなの？」feminine or just an informal particle?

Comment: The の is "feminine-ish" in that males do use it (pretty often really), but it's used more often by females because males often prefer some other form in informal contexts. Also, the な is required before の because 食べ物 is a noun. If you said これは食べ物の？it would literally mean "Is this something of (that belongs/attributes to) food?"

Comment: The なのか？on the other hand is more masculine(-ish). And の -ending can be used (somewhat) more politely with です too, e.g. as in なんですの？ This is quite feminine (and lady-like), while a neutral version would be なんですか？which is just a shorter version of なのですか？